# Using react-with-styles in recompose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

Can someone help me with an example of applying styles using react-with-styles in a higher order component using recompose ?

Specifically, how can we apply styles as explained in this example -- https://github.com/airbnb/react-with-styles#how-to-use -- in a higher order recompose wrapper ?

Comment: Which example are you referring to?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody The usage one -- https://github.com/airbnb/react-with-styles#how-to-use

Answer (score 0):

The *compose* HOC allows you to create components via composition e.g:

```
export default compose(
    withStyles,
    withState('toggleOn', 'toggle', false)
)(Component)
```